# Yii: Redirect in controller to external site in new tab

Tags: php, browser, yii, controller

Is it possible to redirect to an external url inside a Yii controller and open the new page in a new tab?

```
$this->redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

This works fine, but opens in the same tab. Is there a way to open the url in a different tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening new tab on redirect isn't related to server. So you can't force server to open new tab when redirect. Therefore you should control it in your client side. For example you can add `target: "_blank"` attribute inside the links.